# Did Moriko Morioka quit her job or was she fired?

Tags: recovery-of-an-mmo-junkie

Throughout the anime, especially in the first few episodes, Moriko Morioka makes reference to being a NEET on purpose.  At the beginning of the anime, she walks home with some flowers.  Later on in the anime, there are comments and innuendo suggesting she did not quit, but was fired.  At least, she is embarrassed the same way someone who was fired would be.

Did she purposefully quit her job, or was she let go for some reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**She quit on her own.**

While Moriko's introduction [in the beginning of the story in the original source (web manga, Japanese)](http://www.comico.jp/detail.nhn?titleNo=27&articleNo=1) doesn't explicitly state that she quit,

[image: Moriko's introduction]

> 高校卒業から名前の通りモリモリ働いて説サラニートになった。
>   After graduating from high school, as her name suggests, she worked hard ([*morimori*](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A)), then became a rumored "salary(woman) NEET".
>
> その辺の無職とは格が違う。**自らその道を歩んだのだ**。
>   The unemployment is different from the usual. **She chose that path on her own**.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

[her character profile in the anime's official site (Japanese)](http://netoju.com/menu/character) does, instead of "fired" or other reasons.

> 高卒から**働いた会社を辞め**、ニートになった30歳、独身。
>   Single, 30-year-old NEET, **left a company she worked at** after graduating from high school.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Just a bit of fact: It is frowned upon in Japan if you are _fired_ from your workplace. Most of the time, if they think they are about to be fired, they opt to take the initiative and quit instead. Though I doubt Morimori was fired, consider how hardworking she was.

Comment: @Keale same here (Vietnam), usually the boss (or leader, ...) will tell you should leave on your own instead of fire (so no bad record for both company and employee)